# Test Coverage in Select DML Exception

Tags: batch, exception

How can we throw DML exceptions in Batch Start method in apex? I want to cover a code using test class which handles dml exception in select query in batch start method. Query is simple select query

```
global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
      try{
      return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id,Account_Unique__c from Account');
      }catch(Exception e){
     string logId= CustomExceptionController.CreateLog(null,e) ;
     return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you are intent to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting few things here.

> I want to cover a code using test class which handles dml exception in select query in batch start method.

A `SELECT ...` query **never throws** a `DMLException`. `DMLException`, as the name suggests is thrown only on DML Operations. Refer to the description as below from the [documentation for Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm). Also refer to the documentation which specifies what constitutes [DML Operations in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm).

> Any problem with a DML statement, such as an insert statement missing a required field on a record.

In your current form of the code, the execution flow will never reach the `Exception` block. So instead of attempting to *cover* these lines in your test class, you should instead remove the `Exception` block in your batch class, which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something in this lines:

```
}catch(DMLException e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred when inserting contacts records: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.Assert(e.getMessage().contains('Required fields are missing'), 'Update did not fire');
        }
```

If you now the error you just add the `e.getMessage().contains('Part of error')`.

So to test this you need to create a method in your test class that will insert negative parameters or missing data for mandatory fields, something that will trigger the error. You can then in you Developer Console catch the error and use the message on that error to populate your assert.

Check this example from on of my test classes:

```
@isTest static void negtiveInsertion() 
    {

        // Getting test data 
        List<Contact> contacts = Contact_TestFactory.contactsNegativeInput(200);
        Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
        dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = false;

        // Inserting contacts with Want_to_heard_more__c set to true
        Test.startTest();

        try{
            database.insert(contacts, dml);
        }catch(DMLException e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred when inserting contacts records: ' + e.getMessage());
            System.Assert(e.getMessage().contains('Required fields are missing'), 'Update did not fire');
        }
        Test.stopTest();

        // Runing asserts to control insert
        System.assertEquals(200, contacts.size()); 



    }
```

Comment: I want to throw an error in select query and not in insert query

Comment: Umm, **SELECT** is not a DML operation. Can you elaborate a bit more on this case?

Comment: I want to throw an exception not necessarily dml which runs when I execute select query inside Batch start method

Comment: You want to throw and error when a query is been executed? Is this what you are asking? By "execute". what it is that you mean? Returning results from that query? What criteria is the one you are intending to preform here? Could you tell us the value of doing such error handling operation. Please, give more details in order to understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish. It looks like you are also using  Custom Exception structure... will be nice to see and understand this part too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot contrive to make this code throw an exception because there isn't a catchable exception that would be thrown here.

```
try {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id,Account_Unique__c from Account');
} catch(Exception e) {
    String logId = CustomExceptionController.CreateLog(null,e) ;
    return null;
}
```

You should simply remove the exception handler.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator('Select Id,Account_Unique__c from Account');
```